# Append string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string

I want to execute this query as you can see :

```
DECLARE @site_value INT;
SET @site_value = 1310;

WHILE @site_value <= 1396
BEGIN
  ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksDW
  ADD FILE
  (NAME = N'data_2002',

  FILENAME = N'C:\symfadb2filegroup\data_'+@site_value+'.ndf',
  SIZE = 5000MB,
  MAXSIZE = 10000MB,
  FILEGROWTH = 500MB)
  TO FILEGROUP [Filegroup_2002]

   SET @site_value = @site_value + 1;
END;
```

But I get this error in this part `+@site_value`

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
>   Incorrect syntax near '+'.

I used `CONVERT` and `CONCAT` but I get the same error.

Comment: you will need to use dynamic sql

Comment: Try to concat "C:\symfadb2filegroup\data_'+@site_value+'.ndf'," in variable and assign this variable to FileName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to use dynamic sql like below

```
 set @Sql=' ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksDW
  ADD FILE
  (NAME = N''data_2002''

  FILENAME = N''C:\symfadb2filegroup\data_'''+cast(@site_value  as varchar(4))+'.ndf'',
  SIZE = 5000MB,
  MAXSIZE = 10000MB,
  FILEGROWTH = 500MB)
  TO FILEGROUP [Filegroup_2002]'
  print @Sql
```

total code below

```
DECLARE @site_value INT;
SET @site_value = 1310;

declare @Sql nvarchar(max)

WHILE @site_value <= 1396
BEGIN
 set @Sql=' ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksDW
  ADD FILE
  (NAME = N''data_2002''

  FILENAME = N''C:\symfadb2filegroup\data_'''+cast(@site_value  as varchar(4))+'.ndf'',
  SIZE = 5000MB,
  MAXSIZE = 10000MB,
  FILEGROWTH = 500MB)
  TO FILEGROUP [Filegroup_2002]'
  print @Sql
  exec(@sql)


   SET @site_value = @site_value + 1;
END;
```